# How to loop through a page with multiple objects

Tags: html, ruby, loops, nokogiri, watir

I'm trying to make a scraper for a market website that lists their content in a weird way.
For each item on the list, I have to click it to find the price, and once I've clicked it and return after the data has been parsed, the order of the list of items might have changed.

The is no specific way to refer to each "link" using Watir, so to actually successfully parse the price of all the items in an orderly fashion is outside of my knowledge.

I use Watir to access an item `rb browser.element(:text => 'ItemName').click`.  That is fine if it was just the one item I wanted to parse data from using Nokogiri.

```html
<div id="market" class="itemList active" style="height: 396px;" data-category="30">
    <div class="item" data-mainkey="4601" data-count="40503" data-grade="0">
        <div class="thumbImg" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://akamai-webcdn.kgstatic.net/TradeMarket/Common/item/4601.png&quot;)"></div>
        <div class="content"><p>Ash Timber</p><p class="gray"></p></div>
        <div class="count">40503</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-mainkey="4602" data-count="266" data-grade="0">
    <div class="thumbImg" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://akamai-webcdn.kgstatic.net/TradeMarket/Common/item/4602.png&quot;)"></div>
    <div class="content"><p>Maple Timber</p><p class="gray"></p></div>
    <div class="count">266</div>
</div>
```

That is how the list would look, except it's a few hundred more articles.

```rb
browser.element(:text => 'Materials').click
sleep 2
browser.element(:text => 'Wood').click
sleep 2
browser.element(:text => 'Ash Timber').click
sleep 2


page = Nokogiri::HTML(browser.html)
page.xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/main/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/p[1]').each do |nc|
  @name = (nc).text
  puts @name
end
```

Is there a way to iterate through each item based on their "data-mainkey", since that is the identifier of the item from what I've seen.

This is currently the project and it outputs the name of the item just fine.

I would like the project to go through the list of articles, enter each and parse out the value to an array and show the result, but I have no clue how to approach this.

Comment: A lot of times, when dealing with dynamic pages, you have to dig into the logic of the JavaScript, then replicate it in the Ruby code. That allows you to more programmatically walk through the page, pick out the data you need, apply some Ruby code to it and determine what link the JavaScript would open, and tell Ruby to do it directly.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Your code doesn't do anything if we try to run it, and without that you're asking us to write a test harness, recreate the HTML, and then try to determine the problem, however that's a lot of room for error in providing you a solution. Instead we need something more definite to help you.

Comment: It might be worthwile to check what framework the shop uses and then access the item iteratively (e.g. the shop might expose `https://shop.url/products/1` even if it usually will have a speaking URL - for magento it is `/catalog/product/view/id`). With good luck you can access a list of products via an open REST API, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the page flow correctly, but it sounds like you need to:

- Store all of the data_mainkey values
- Iterate through each of the mainkey values - re-locating the element each time

The code would look like:

```
main_keys = browser.divs(class: 'item').map(&:data_mainkey)
main_keys.each do |key|
  # Depending how the page is written, the div(class: 'content') might not be necessary
  browser.div(data_mainkey: key).div(class: 'content').click

  # Get the price

  # Navigate back to the list page
end
```